# Autodividers listview with collapsable option

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on a `listview` which has auto dividers based on date it is a very long list & `data-autodividers='true'` works fine but I want to further improve it by making the `listview` collapsible on date.

This can be done from back-end using c# (I am working on an asp.net webform mobile website) where I group my list based on Month-Year and make each group collapsible.

But I would love to do it with jQuery as I do for `autodivider`. I have set up same on jsFiddle.

**http://jsfiddle.net/5PnBT/10/**

**How can I make these auto-divider collapsible using jQuery *without* doing it from code-behind file (c#)?**

I did not see where jquerymobile has this as a build in option.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page-wrapper", function () {
    $("#hp-latest-articles").listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.attr('date');
            return out;
        }
    }).listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Your code above works fine. You need to convert the `listview` to a `collapsible` set.

Comment: @Omar:- I am not sure how to do that with jQuery, otherwise i have to do everything from codebehind (c#). I wish it had a built in option to make it collapsible.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. I'm reading about creating `collapsible` list dynamically. I will give it a try ;) It's somehow similar to the dividers in your code.

Comment: I have managed to convert the list items into collapsible. the code doesn't work on jsfiddle, tested it on desktop. check the code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rZHMv/

Comment: Appreciate your help, Unfortunately it is not working on local machine &  listview wont show-up when i view your example in IE 9. JAZAKALLAH KHAIR.. I will try to figure out .. I like your approach i will also find a way to add & wrap collapsible `DIV` around the groups.

Comment: Wa jazak akhi :) I'll keep trying!

Comment: Your code works fine on my Firefox, it's just the `pageinit` event which doesn't get triggered. See http://jsfiddle.net/5PnBT/8/

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem, I think you just have to use the **$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.autodividersSelector** option. I had a similar problem, so if you need to list them according to the date attribute on the single element, do:

```
 $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.autodividersSelector = function( element )       {
    return (element.attr('date'))       

  };
});
```

I prepared a jsbin for that: http://jsbin.com/enuwoj/1/edit

Comment: Your solution is grouping by date but my actual question is that i want to make it collapsible by default so that when user click on date it will expand the list & show article for that particular date only... Example http://jsfiddle.net/5PnBT/9/

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to your problem.

1. Either you use the collapsible list sets on the jQuery Mobile side, then you will be able to reach exactly what you are looking for. You might nee to edit the looks of the element using CSS to make it look like a listview.

http://jsfiddle.net/rc9Gk/

```
     <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Title</h3>
             <ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul>
     </div>
```

1. Second solution would be to apply custom event handlers on click event of the listview control. Whenever a click event occurs on a list divider you can hide the following list elements till the next auto-divider. This solution needs a bit of coding. If this solution fits you, I can write that code for you do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is solved by adding the following to the bottom of your original fiddle

```
$('.ui-li-divider').click( function(ev ){
  var li = $(ev.target).next(':not(.ui-li-divider)');
  while ( li.length > 0 ) {
      li.toggle();
      li = li.next(':not(.ui-li-divider)');
  }
});
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5PnBT/50/)

Basically, everytime you click a divider, it looks for all following LIs until the next divider and toggles their visibility.

Comment: awesome, any suggestion to add +/- icons based on state ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need either `<div data-role="collapsible">` or `<div data-role="collapsible-set">`, depending on if you wanted to group them or not.

If you want them pre-collapsed by default, include the `data-collapsed="true"` attribute as well.